# how to set title to first navigation controller in a page that uses tab view controller.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

we have used the following code in app delegate. but we are getting error in the setTitle function of navigation controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* viewController3=[[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, nil];
    NavigationViewController* navigationViewController=[[NavigationViewController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
  self.navigationItem.title=@"news";
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"your navigation title";
```

use this in which view controller you want to show the title

Answer (score 0):

```
[viewController1 setTitle:@"Title1"];
[viewController2 setTitle:@"Title2"];
[viewController3 setTitle:@"Title3"];
```

It ist neither the navigation controller nor the tab bar controller that carries the title.